# Where is the source for rails command line like new, generate located?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I would like to know when we run commands like rails new, rails generate. Which files are actually executed. In general for other tools like rake, rspec( not sure they are called command line tools ) or any other such gem, which files are executed first( at the beginning ).
Thanks.

Comment: No, can you elaborate further where to look for that

Comment: The answer to the question is really just to look at the source which like almost everything today is hosted on Github and can be found with a bare minimum of effort. Answering this question is somewhat problematic in that any changes to the implementation will invalidate the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of them are located in this folder https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/3be590edbedab8ddcacdf72790d50c3cf9354434/railties/lib/rails/commands

For instance this https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3be590edbedab8ddcacdf72790d50c3cf9354434/railties/lib/rails/commands/application/application_command.rb calls the app generator https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3be590edbedab8ddcacdf72790d50c3cf9354434/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb

Comment: Thanks, just fyi also found out it is listed as executable in railties.gemspec file.

Comment: One problem with this answer is that it won't age well. You're linking to the master branch and any changes in the implementation means its just a collection of dead links. Use permalinks to a specific commit/tag instead.